# Excel VBA Function Fails but Formula works in sheet

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

Weird Math Error in VBA for Excel

Hi all, would love feedback on unsusual error I'm getting.

Very strange.  I have a simple formula that works great if I
only use it in a normal sheet cell and copy it down by columns,
but if I try to do a simple iteration in vba code to perform the same function I get the wrong values.

Description : A number is squared, then divided by another value 
between 0.99 to 1.99, next the modulus is taken and then
the number is squared again and the whole formula repeated.
If I copy the formula statement down column wise it calcs fine, 
including reasonable decimal accuracy.

There are four inputs ; 
base value (inputx)
decx = divisor
mod value

The first formula placed at (E2) looks like ; =MOD(((B2^2)/$B$3),$B$4)

In (E3) this statement is placed  ; =MOD(((E2^2)/$B$3),$B$4)

Then this exact same statement is copied down, columnwise to the next 98 cells.

All great, no problem.  It seems accurate value wise, right to decimal 
precision, with values past the decimal point showing in all column cells.

Some sample input values for testing ;

INPUTX -->  231
DECX    1.010101
MOD 400
LOOPTIMES   100

But when I try to implement this is Excel VBA code (Excel 2007)
I often get the wrong values and absolutely no values past the decimal point ever show.

Have tried using all kinds of different data types ; single, double, variant, etc... but all values returned by the VBA function I made always returns
whole numbers, and is often wrong and certainly does not agree with the
values returned by the simple column based statements.

Have tried to find ways around this or to fix this, came across "CDEC", tried
this and nothing changed.  Totally stumped and would love some insight into 
if this can be fixed so that the function loop returns the same values with
same kind of decimal precision as the column based statements and 
would greatly appreciate feedback on how mthis can be done.

Am including my sample code below ;

```
Public Function SQRD(inputx As Variant, looptime As Variant, decx As Variant) As Variant

Application.Volatile

Dim Count As Integer

SQRD = CDec(inputx)

'Dim decx As variant

Count = 1

For Count = 1 To looptime
    SQRD = CDec(SQRD ^ 2)  '+ looptime
    SQRD = CDec(SQRD Mod 400 / decx)
Next Count

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots amiss with your code. No need for looping as far as I can see, and you're dividing after the mod not before

This seems to do the trick

```
Public Function NuFunc(InputX As Variant, DecX As Variant) As Variant
  NuFunc = ((InputX ^ 2) / DecX) Mod 400
End Function
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback - I get what you mean, that is helpful and I appreciate that but it does not fix the problem.

When the function runs with input value of "404.0404"
for 100 iterations, it returns the incorrect value of 1
where as the sheet column formula returns the correct
value of "72.18545607"

The UDF VBA function is not retaining any values past the decimal position
nor is it properly calculating the end result.

Comment: I suspect this is related to data type and how excel is handling the calcs in
VBA, but I cant figure out how to fix this as I have tried all known relevant data types.

Its easy to see what I mean by simply entering any value for input thats
a rational number and for any loops higher than 10, the spreadsheet using basic repeat and copy columnwise statements of what I mentioned above ;

"The first formula placed at (E2) looks like ; =MOD(((B2^2)),$B$4)
In (E3) this statement is placed ; =MOD(((E2^2)),$B$4)"

Comment: Then comparing the 100th cell to the 100th iteration of the function demonstrates the discrepancy, I just want the function to return the same value and accuracy that the far more cumbersome sheet / column based
approach produces

Comment: Also, in the code snippet you provided above ( thanks very much for that btw) - I want to be able to enter the number of loops / iterations, I do not want to just get the single square of an input, but I need to recurse this while retaining accuracy and decimal values

Comment: Note to self .. Don't answer a question and then go to bed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I will only address your use of the VBA `Mod` operator.  It is **NOT** equivalent to the Excel `MOD` function.  In particular, the VBA `Mod` operator will round floating point numbers to integers before performing the operation.

To use a VBA function that mimics the Excel `MOD` function, use something like:

```
Function xlMOD(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
    xlMOD = a - (b * (a \ b))
End Function
```

**EDIT**
There seems to be a bug in VBA (or a documentation error).  In the formula above, the `\` operator is supposed to be the integer division operator. It does return an integer result. However, it does not truncate, rather it rounds.  Actually, what it may be doing, is performing VBA type rounding on the number and divisor, before returning the result.

Therefore, a proper vba function to mimic the Excel `MOD` function would be:

```
Function xlMOD(a As Double, b As Double) As Double   
    xlMOD = a - Int(a / b) * b
End Function
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189753/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-rosenfeld-excel-vba-function-fails-but-formula-works).

Comment: Hi Ron, I just downloaded Xnumbers for XP and will try it out with my Excel 2007 version and see what happens - is it ok to ask, did you write code / script for xnumbers like a mod function for it to test with?  If so could you share that with me?